# Python AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute '_sID'

Tags: python, eclipse

I get an error in python ecplise and i didn't found the solution to solve it..

Class:

```
class Student:
    '''
    This class is used to store data about the students
    It contains:
        sID - id of student
        sName - name of student
    '''
    def __init__(self, sID, sName):
        '''
        Initialized the student
        '''
        self._sID = sID
        self._sName = sName


    def getID(self):
        '''
        Return student id
        '''
        return self._sID

    def setID(self, ID):
        self._sID = ID

    def setName(self, name):
        self._sName = name

    def getName(self):
        '''
        Return student name
        '''
        return self._sName

    def __str__(self):
        '''
        Converts the student into printable text
        '''
        msg ='ID: ' + str(self._sID) + ', Name: ' + self._sName
        return msg

    def __eq__(self, s):
        '''
        Checks if two students have the same ID and name
        '''
        return self._sID == s._sID and self._sName == s._sName
```

Below is the erorr with attribute:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\crist\workspace\lab5_7\appStart.py", line 16, in <module>
    ui.mainMenu()
  File "C:\Users\crist\workspace\lab5_7\UI\ui.py", line 80, in mainMenu
    self._searchElementMenu(cmd[1])
  File "C:\Users\crist\workspace\lab5_7\UI\ui.py", line 57, in _searchElementMenu
    self._controller.searchElement(cType, cSearch)
  File "C:\Users\crist\workspace\lab5_7\controller\controller.py", line 27, in searchElement
    if isinstance(lst[i], Student) == True and lst[i] == eSearch:
  File "C:\Users\crist\workspace\lab5_7\domain\student.py", line 55, in __eq__
    return self._sID == s._sID and self._sName == s._sName
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_sID'
```

Can someone help me?

I can give u more code if is necessary.

The sID is the unique id for every student, and i need this function to verify if more students have the same id.

Thank you so much !

Comment: Your `eSearch` variable is a string, not an instance of `Student`. You could update `__eq__` to check if `s` is a string and do the compare directly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the `=` operator, with an `Student` instance and a string.

The error tells that a string instance does not have a `_sID` *variable* like:

```
"test"._sID
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - getting the same error message when setting environment in PythonWin. I haven't changed anything, but restarted PythonWin and it was working again as usual.

Comment: Please provide more explanation in your answer.